# Mockmvc using spock test error

Tags: spring, testing, controller, spock

I'm using the spock framework to write tests for a spring 3 controller class. I get the following error while trying to execute one of the tests (GET request). Note that all other tests (POST requests) in the same class work as expected.

Controller signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{accountHolderId}/xyz", method = GET)
public @ResponseBody BaseResponse getHistoryByHolderId(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable String accountHolderId)
```

Spock Test

```
def "GetHistoryByHolderId"() {

        def accountHolderId = 'x@y.com'

        when: 'an http call is performed to get fund transfer history by accountHolderId'
        def response = mockMvc.perform(
                get('/{accountHolderId}/xyz',accountHolderId))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn().response

        def result = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.contentAsString)
    }
```

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.

Comment: What does the controller class and spock test look like? Please update your question with more details.

Comment: updated @SzymonStepniak

Comment: Note that I also tried adding `@PathVariable("accountHolderId") String accountHolderId` to the controller signature but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue. The reason was that I was spying on the controller class i.e. the method target was on a Spock proxy class (instead of proxying the original method) and spring wasn't able to read annotations properly. Hence, it wasn't recognising path variables and request parameters.